# Laravel form empty post

Tags: laravel

I need to pass variables from the index page to a function but the post is empty when checked, what am I doing wrong? is there a better way to achieve this?

**index page**

```
        {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-inline', 'method' => 'POST', 'action' => array('InvoiceController@bill', $domain->id))) !!}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ route('domains.show', $domain->id) }}">{{ $domain->id }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ $domain->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $domain->expiry_date }}</td>
                            <td>Domain</td>
            <td>{{ $domain->ClientName }}</td>
            <td>  {!! link_to_route('domains.edit', 'Edit', array($domain->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) !!}
                {!! Form::submit('Bill', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) !!} </td>

        </tr>

        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**invoice controller**

```
public function bill(Domain $domain) {
    dd($domain);
    $bill = new BilltoKashflow();
    $bill->bill($domain);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `$domain->id`, so your method should look like this to make it work:

```
public function bill($domainId)
{
    ....
}
```

If you want to pass `$domain` object, try to send `$domain`, instead of `$domain->id` and use this method:

```
public function bill($domain)
{
    dd($domain);
}
```

Comment: thanks the second part of your answer is what i needed

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any form inputs in your example code, if there are no form inputs then no data will be passed back to your controller.

I'm assuming you'll need to do replace all your table variables with form inputs like so:

```
<td><input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $domain->name }}"></td>
```

Or

```
<td>{!! Form::text('name', $domain->name) !!}</td>
```